# 2009 Town and Contry - Doors lock when opening driver's side door

Tags: electrical, locks, chrysler, town-and-country

I've got a 2009 Chrysler Town and Country Touring with the 3.8L V6. Recently, the interior doors have begun locking when the driver's side door is opened. Specifically, the moment I pull the door handle to it's furthest-out position. On rare occasions, it has also locked when closing the door.

I pulled the interior door panel and inspected the wiring for shorts, mechanical rubbing, and loose contacts, but there was nothing visibly wrong there. I'll go ahead and list some other troubleshooting and observations:

- The key fob locks and unlocks all doors properly
- The passenger-side lock buttons lock and unlock all doors properly
- The driver's side door lock/unlock buttons do not work, but the window and mirror buttons do
- With the driver's side button panel unplugged, the doors will still lock when opening the door.
- Unplugging the bottom-most harness from the door control module (which includes the wires from the button panel) and then plugging it back in causes the doors to lock.

All of that has me thinking that the Door Control Module is the problem. However, it's not a cheap part, so I thought I'd throw this out here and see if anyone else has had a similar problem with Chrysler/Dodge products from this same era.

Edit:
For clarification, when I say driver's side button panel, it's this guy, with the smaller, 3-pin connector:
[image: Driver's Side Button Panel]